# SQL Order by and top 1 didnt work on my code they just counting

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-order-by

so I have the task of asking to find the supplier ID that sends the most products in Northwind. This is my code

```
select s.SupplierID, count(p.ProductID) 
from Suppliers s join Products p
on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
group by s.SupplierID
having count(p.ProductID) in 
(select top 1 count(p.ProductID)
from Products
order by count(p.ProductID) desc)
```

but what i got is my result they just counting without top 1 and the order by doesnt work

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (That query will not work on both...)

Answer (score 2):

I would just use `ORDER BY` and `TOP`:

```
select top (1) s.SupplierID, count(*) cnt
from Suppliers s 
join Products p on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
group by s.SupplierID
order by cnt desc
```

If you want to allow ties, then use `top (1) with ties` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `group by` in the subquery:

```
having count(p.ProductID) in (select top 1 count(p.ProductID)
                              from Products
                              group by SupplierID
                              order by count(p.ProductID) desc
                             )
```

However, a much simpler formulation uses window functions:

```
select top (1) p.SupplierID, count(*) as cnt,
from products p 
group by p.SupplierID
order by count(*) desc;
```

Note that you don't need `Suppliers` because the `id` is already in `products` and you are not selecting any other columns.

Also, you may want `select top (1) with ties`, if you want multiple rows in the event of ties.